# How do I use msbuild in Visual Studio's post build event?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event, yui-compressor

I'm trying to configure the [YUICompressor.NET](https://github.com/PureKrome/YUICompressor.NET) in my Visual Studio project.

As I've understood, I have to create a .proj file and add it to my solution. After that, I need to create a post-build event that will build this .proj file and I'll get my desired output (minified js/css files).

So, I have:

[image: visual studio solution explorer]

This .proj contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/MsBuild/2003">

  <UsingTask TaskName="CssCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="\..\packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.7.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="JavaScriptCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="\..\packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.7.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />

  <Target Name="Minify">

    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Single files, listed in order of dependency -->
      <CssFiles Include="Content\*.css"/>
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="Scripts\*.js"/>      
    </ItemGroup>

    <CssCompressorTask
          SourceFiles="@(CssFiles)"
          OutputFile="Content\min.css"
       />

    <JavaScriptCompressorTask
          SourceFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
          OutputFile="Scripts\min.js"
       />

  </Target>
</Project>
```

I'm trying to build it as the following:

[image]

I'm getting the following error:

```
The command "msbuild C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MvcApplicationExample\MvcApplicationExample\YuiCompressorMsBuild.proj" exited with code 9009.
```

This error suggests that "msbuild" is not a valid command. So, how should I build this type of project? (I've followed this tutorial: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFFZ0nQog8U))

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Error 9009 just means "command failed", it doesn't tell you why it failed.  For that, you need to look in the Output window.

Comment: Ty @HansPassant for the hint. My output window shows: `'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. So, how should I build the project? The youtube video shows the presenter executing msbuild through cmd. I thought that I could use it inside the post-build event.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As you said maybe the visual studio cannot find the MSBuild command, try with the following command instead

```
"$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe"
```

That uses the complete path to msbuild.

#### Update (For futures references)

As the [comment by Steve Medley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33470786/1322417), you should not forget the encapsulating quotes.

Comment: msbuild not working for me this way either, not a valid command

Comment: @shyam_ are you see the steve medley comment?

Comment: "you should not forget the encapsulating quotes" indeed!

Answer (score 6):

vfabre is correct to use $(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe but missing one thing. you should encapsulate that in quotes as there will 99.99% of the time be a space in the file path to msbuild

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing that might be a problem is that you want it as a Post-build event but it's set for the Pre-build command line.

Comment: Ty for the observation, but unfortunately it does not solve my issue. I've edited the image. Same error.

Comment: Ah, that just jumped out at me so I was hoping that was all it was.  I'll take a closer look.